# Laravel 6 - whereHasMorph Relationship Return Empty

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel `Polymorphic Relationship`. i have 2 table `Supplier` and `Product` and have `Category` to each table, so i'm decide to use `Polymorphic Relationship`. i want to query `supplier-category` but its return `empty` array.

// My Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['categorizable_type', 'categorizable_id'];

    public function categorizable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

// My Supplier Model

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(\App\Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}
```

// My Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['product_code', 'product_name'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(\App\Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}
```

// And in SupplierController i want to query `categorizable_type`

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // $product = Category::all();
        $product = Category::whereHasMorph('categorizable', Supplier::class , function($query){
                $query->where('categorizable_type', 'like', '%foo%');
        })->get();

        dd($product);
        // return response()->json($product);
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im make it working by change my code like below

```
    $product = Category::whereHasMorph('categorizable', Supplier::class)->get();
```